# What does it mean when the busterJS says TestHelpers in Node Will be Require'd?

Tags: node.js, buster.js

From the documentation **(Emphasiss Mine)**

> Library files to load in script tags in the browser. **This setting
>   should normally not be used for node runs. If it is, files will be
>   `require'd`.** Value is an array of file names and/or glob patterns. Files
>   are loaded in the order provided. It may include duplicates, e.g.
>   ["test/lib/core.js", "test/lib/**/*.js"], files will only be loaded
>   once. testHelpers are loaded after libraries and sources, but before
>   tests.

What does this mean, exactly? When they get `require'd`, what do they get included as? Under what variable name? I have some global methods (`testSetUp` and `testTearDown`) That I like to reuse between tests. According to this, I can only use these methods between tests when I'm testing in the browser, not when I'm testing in Node.

Here's my config file:

var config = module.exports;

```
config['Browser Tests'] = {
    rootPath: '../',
    environment: 'browser',
    sources: [
        'src/*.js'
    ],
    deps: [
        'submodules/d3/d3.v2.min.js'
    ],
    testHelpers: [
        'test/helpers/*.js'
    ],
    tests: [
        'test/test_*.js'
    ]
};

config["Node tests"] = {
    rootPath: '../',
    environment: "node",
    tests: [
        'test/test_*.js'
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the documentation is telling you is that the files will be required, but their exports will be lost. So unless your helpers modify global objects, this is not useful on node.

However, you are free to put shared helpers in a separate file and require yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @christian. By the way, I bought your book on TDD and JavaScript and absolutely fell in love with it. It has _drastically_ improved my JavaScript and I've been able to use what I've learned from it to build some pretty neat stuff.